# Was the Shamir worm used for the second Beis Hamikdash?

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash, architecture-design, bugs

Shlomo Hamelech used a 'Shamir' worm to quarry and cut the stones for the first Beis Hamikdash. Did they still have this worm for the second Beis Hamikdash?

If not, how were the stones cut (as no metal implements were allowed to be used)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the Mishna ([Sotah 9:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h35.htm)), the Shamir wasn't extinct until the destruction of the second Beis Hamikdash.

> ט:יב  משמתו נביאים הראשונים, בטלו אורים ותומים.  משחרב בית המקדש, בטל השמיר ונופת צופים;‏

Incidentally, there is no mention of the Shamir in Rambam. Ever the rationalist, Rambam doesn't believe in demons (which were associated with the Shamir). He held that it was okay to quarry and cut the stones outside the Beis Hamikdash area, and then be brought in (See [Beis Habechira 1:8](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/8101.htm)).

Likely, Rambam is following the [Mechilta](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%90_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9B#.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7_.D7.9B.D7.91_.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A7.29.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7.29) (Shemos 20:22) who holds that the prohibition only applies to the stones for the Mizbeach, and not to any other stones which may be hewn.

Comment: Who disagrees with the Mechilta?

Comment: You have to learn the Sugya in Sotah 48b. R' Nechemia is of the opinion that it was used to cut the precious stones of the ephod and choshen.

Comment: A note: you reference Beis Habechira 1:8....in the version you linked to it wasn't in the regular "8", but the content you mention isn't mentioned until 1:9 (which could be 8) .....you may want to clarify that in your answer

Comment: @Shokhet Mechon Mamre uses both, hence the 9 in brackets, too. I found the reference then linked it. If you know of a Rambam online that matches the standard text & numbering, let me know and I'll relink it.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=8&hilchos=41&perek=1&halocha=8

Comment: Why does משחרב בית המקדש mean the second temple?